# Windows 10 second screen shared across all virtual desktops

Tags: windows-10, virtual-desktop, task-view

I was wondering if it was at all possible to share the second screen across all virtual desktops instead of it switching along with the first screen to the new virtual desktop. This feature is in ubuntu's gnome-shell and I really enjoyed the feature there.

Comment: No;  The desktop doesn't work like that in Windows.  Desktop is on all detected displays a single entity.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but not with built-in Windows 10 virtual desktops. You'll need to download a 3rd party program that's is very well made called Dexpot. Use the feature called "on all workspaces"

http://www.dexpot.de/