# Windows 10 virtual desktops, make second monitor not change/static

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors, virtual-desktop

I am unable to find a way to setup my 2nd monitor to remain static with the open desktop/app when I am swapping virtual desktop on the main monitor. Seems the official support thread was also not able to find a native solution: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/multiple-monitors-and-virtual-desktops-in-windows/6dfff267-ede5-474a-a0bc-ea868eafaeb7

The question from 3 years ago only has 1 answer with a third party non-free solution: [Windows 10 second screen shared across all virtual desktops](https://superuser.com/questions/960838/windows-10-second-screen-shared-across-all-virtual-desktops) The product recommended seems dated, last news post in sidebar is form early 2016.

Is there no built-in way to do this by now?

Answer (score 8):

While I don't believe it's natively possible to make one display static, you can make windows static across all virtual desktops, which is an effective work-around if you just dedicate one display to a few apps. The following works for me as of Windows 10 version 20H2.

- Press **Windows + Tab** to open Task View
- Right-Click on the desired window
- Select **Show this window on all desktops**

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Thank you so much. It was exactly what I was looking for. 
I just don't understand why Microsoft doesn't make it more clear by providing/showing a pin button/icon. (I'm on Windows 11)

Answer (score 2):

I'd just like to add to what Sam Morgan said, that you can select 'Show windows from this app on all desktops' as well (in the same context menu), which will make all instances of that program appear on all desktops, and will persist even after closing the program.

I'm on Windows 11 Enterprise 21H2.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).